# Error creating lucene index in Azure Blob with Azuredirectory

Tags: c#, azure, lucene, azure-blob-storage, lucene.net

I've been pulling my hair trying to get this to work. 
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Use lucene.Net for search functionality
2. host this on azure

The problem :

I used this tutorial [Lucene.Net ultra fast search for MVC or WebForms site => made easy!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms) to get started and it worked perfectly while retrieving from my localdb to create index files in  my local disk and subsequently calling rest methods to perform the search.

Now I am trying to convert part of the code to reference the blob instead. 
so the original is this:

```
private static string _luceneDir =Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "lucene_index");
private static FSDirectory _directoryTemp;
private static FSDirectory _directory {
get {
    if (_directoryTemp == null) _directoryTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(_luceneDir));
    if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(_directoryTemp)) IndexWriter.Unlock(_directoryTemp);
    var lockFilePath = Path.Combine(_luceneDir, "write.lock");
    if (File.Exists(lockFilePath)) File.Delete(lockFilePath);
    return _directoryTemp;
}}
```

I changed it to this:

```
private static AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")),"SearchCatalog");
private static AzureDirectory _directoryTemp;


        private static AzureDirectory _directory
        {
            get
            {
                // if (_directoryTemp == null) _directoryTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(_luceneDir));
                if (_directoryTemp == null) _directoryTemp = azureDirectory;
                if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(_directoryTemp)) IndexWriter.Unlock(_directoryTemp);
                return _directoryTemp;
            }
        }
```

I took away the last 2 lines as I had no idea how to get the filepath of a blobl storage in azure, and from my understanding its not possible.

What happens now is the container in the blob gets created but the index files are not created and I get a http 404 error.
Detailed Error:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.",
  "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException",
  "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(StorageUri blobUri, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(String blobName, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Lucene.Net.Store.Azure.AzureLock.IsLocked()\r\n   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.IsLocked(Directory directory)\r\n   at brickandmortarv1.Models.LuceneSearch.get__directory()\r\n   at brickandmortarv1.Models.LuceneSearch.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(IEnumerable`1 products)\r\n   at brickandmortarv1.Controllers.LuceneController.Get(String searchterm)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance , really quite lost what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the following code

```html
     if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(_directoryTemp)) IndexWriter.Unlock(_directoryTemp);
```

After remove above code, it works. Here is the screenshot that works on my side:

[image]

The following is my code:

```html
 private static AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=jastorage1;AccountKey=***"),"sample"

        private static AzureDirectory _directoryTemp;
        private static AzureDirectory _directory
        {
            get
            {
                // if (_directoryTemp == null) _directoryTemp = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(_luceneDir));
                if (_directoryTemp == null) _directoryTemp = azureDirectory;
               // if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(_directoryTemp)) IndexWriter.Unlock(_directoryTemp);
                _directoryTemp.ClearLock("write.lock");
                return _directoryTemp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: apologies, I got busy this week. Ill try this tonight and mark the answer if it works.